# What's the meaning of " ask with low respect"?

Tags: phrases

> — How’s the body?
> — Fine. How are you?
> — Just keeping alive, M’Coy said.
> His eyes on the black tie and clothes he **asked with low respect**:
> — Is there any... no trouble I hope? I see you’re...
> — O, no, Mr Bloom said. Poor Dignam, you know. The funeral is today.

Which is from Ulysses.

Does it mean asked in a low voice and with respect? is this a weird usage ? ...

Comment: It's anybody's guess what it means, unless there are some Joyce scholars here. Ulysses is mostly famous for having weird English usage. Only people with a very strong interest in the use of English read that book. Even highly literate people don't understand it, even with help from scholars. It's probably the last book I would recommend learning English from, but if it motivates you to read, go for it! Just don't expect that everything in there is considered correct form.

Comment: @gotube yes, I think the Style of Stream of Consciousness gives the lawful reason to not write in a grammatical way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase could have two meanings, depending on the usage of the word low:

If using the word low as a measure (as in "low standards"), asking with low respect would mean **asking the question without any special regard towards the person**.

If using the word low as in sound ("low volume"), it could mean **asking the question quietly with respect/regard for the person**.

Based on the context given, it's most likely the second. However, it could mean either of the two.

Comment: thank you, maybe Joyce expressed 2 meanings in the same time, I think he likes wordplaying.

Comment: Joyce's writing is very enigmatic. I wouldn't doubt that he meant both at once.